# Setting up LaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I having a lot of trouble with my TeX setup.

I have some TeX files in a folder, which is synced with Dropbox. I'm using a MacBook and TexWorks. Things no longer work as they should and trying to debug things is a nightmare.

The major problem is running `bibtex` or `biber`, with hundreds of errors thrown up, such as:

- `Missing \endcsname inserted`.
- `Package keyval Error: useeditor undefined`.
- `Package etoolbox Error: Toggle 'cms@reprint' undefined`.
- `Package biblatex Error: Option 'sorting=cms' invalid`.

My question relates to how to set things up so that the TeX file can find all the files it needs to create my file.

Comment: Can you try to temporarily turn off syncing with Dropbox and try again? It would also be good if we knew something about what TeX Distribution you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using "TeX Live 2017".

Turning off syncing does not seem to make a difference.

I can make a PDF, but the first page is simply this line:

"pubstatereprintorigyearyearyearorigyearendyearendyearorigyear>endyear"

Comment: I think we’ll need an example of a file that causes the problem. Also where do you store these files and what type of files are they?

Comment: Here is text doc that generates 99 errors

Comment: `\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}


\begin{document} 

Test Doc 

\end{document}`

Comment: the problem is the line

`\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}`

Comment: But you also never designate a .bib file, cite anything or print the bibliography.

Comment: Does the small document really gives errors? Did you delete the auxiliary files (bbl and aux) before the test? If yes something is not up-to-date and you should show the log-file.

Comment: This looks like version incompatibilities. Make sure that your versions of `biblatex-chicago`, `biblatex` and Biber are compatible. (On TeX live you can update all packages using `tlmgr`.) If you are syncing across different computers, make sure that the versions on all machines agree. Please edit your question to show a minimal example that throws errors for you, show the exact error messages from the `.log` file.

Comment: @moewe - you are right - I had to downgrade `biber` and `biblatex` to be compatible with `biblatex-chicago`

Comment: Mhhh. I'd have thought that if all packages are updated to their newest versions things should work. What versions are you using?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include an MWE that did not work for you as well as a copy of the error messages you receive in the `.log` file? Check your versions of `biblatex`, Biber and `biblatex-chicago` and report them as well.

Comment: Any news here? Can you provide the additional details I asked for?

Comment: Any news here? At the moment your question is very unclear and lacks important detail.

Comment: The solution, as mentioned above, was solved when I downgraded biber and biblatex to be compatible with biblatex-chicago. 

Any MWE will only reproduce the errors when one has up to date versions (Biber 2.10 and biblatex 3.10)

But as the biblatex-chicago manual says: "You should use the latest version [of biber], 2.7, to work with biblatex 3.7 and biblatex-chicago."

Issue closed.